# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() returns inconsistent information on different computers

Tags: c#, timezone

If I use

```
foreach (TimeZoneInfo info in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
    if (info.ToString()...
```

to acquire a list of timezone strings, then on some systems it returns strings prefixed with (GMT) and on other systems with (UTC).  Not 100% sure about this, but it seems Vista lists (GMT) values, and Windows 7 lists (UTC) values, and Windows Server lists (GMT)

What is going on, and can I get Windows 7 to list the Vista GMT values?  I want a consistent list that will work across all Windows machines.

fyi In the same system I am also using the following line to populate an MVC dropdown:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Timezone,new SelectList(TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())) %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a constant list? This sounds like data that's displayed to the user, and thus is most likely localized. I'm sure there is some property that gives you a unique, stable id. But that id is most likely only designed for computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `TimeZoneInfo.ToString()`, which uses `TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName`. That simply *is* system-dependent - it's the same list (as far as I can tell) which is displayed if you go to edit the system time zone via the clock. (I've just looked on Vista and Windows 7 machines, and seen the same names you've just described.)

If you're looking for a consistent name, use the `Id` property instead. If you want a consistent mapping from ID to some known set of display names, you'll need to set that up yourself (e.g. via a single database all your systems talk to). You *shouldn't* display the `Id` property itself to users, as it's pretty confusing - it's almost always the *standard time* ID, which would confuse people when they're in daylight saving time.

If you want to push the boat out, the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) has information about how to display time zones to users (see `core/common/bcp47/timezone.xml`) but that uses the zoneinfo IDs, so you'd then need to map those back to the Windows system IDs (which is doable; that information is in CLDR as well, in `core/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml`).

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'll follow your advice on this and setup a custom list myself.

Answer (score 0):

RE: "Not 100% sure about this, but it seems Vista lists (GMT) values, and Windows 7 lists (UTC) values, and Windows Server lists (GMT)"

Windows Server 2008 R2 returns UTC.  Server 2003 returned GMT.